# ReactStrap NavLinks are broken when rendered via a component

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

The following code renders my NavLinks properly in my ReactStrap DropdownMenu:

```
<!-- RENDERS CORRECTLY -->

<Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
    <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
        <DropdownToggle nav caret> A dropdown menu </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu>
            <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to=“/url1”> item 1 </NavLink>
            <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to=“/url2”> item 2 </NavLink>
          </DropdownMenu>
     </UncontrolledDropdown>
</Nav>
```

But if I move the DropdownMenu into a separate component as follows, returning exactly the same JSX, the css is screwy and the resulting a elements have "to" attributes instead of "href" attributes, so the links don't work.

```
<!-- BREAKS -->

<Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
    <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
        <DropdownToggle nav caret> A dropdown menu </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenuComponent/>
     </UncontrolledDropdown>
</Nav>

...

class DropdownMenuComponent extends Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <DropdownMenu>
               <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to=“/url1”> item 1 </NavLink>
            <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to=“/url2”> item 2 </NavLink>
            </DropdownMenu>
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?  It's disconcerting to use ReactStrap if I can't count on basic nesting of components.

Comment: I'm sure this a typo, but in your second code sample, I don't see anyplace where `DropdownMenuComponent` is being used (such as nested inside your `Nav`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the links in the `<DropdownItem>` component and then they'll render correctly.

I put together a working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9zn1ly75po)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Nav,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  NavLink
} from "reactstrap";
import "bootstrap-css-only";


const DropdownComponent = () => (
  <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownItem>
      <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to="/url1">
        item 1
      </NavLink>
    </DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>
      <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to="/url2">
        item 2
      </NavLink>
    </DropdownItem>
  </DropdownMenu>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
      <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
        <DropdownToggle nav caret>
          A dropdown menu
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownComponent />
      </UncontrolledDropdown>
    </Nav>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Sweet - thx!  It's still puzzling to me that the DropdownItem wrapper is only necessary when providing the DropdownMenu via a component.

Comment: @MikeCantor I'm glad that it helped you. You should always wrap children of `DropdownMenu` in the `DropdownItem` component per the documentation. That is what the library is looking for, anything else is undefined behavior. If this answered your question please use the checkmark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ReactStrap before, and from my experience, you often have to use Bootstrap classes in place of components if you start getting wonky styling attributes.

Also, in your second example when the code breaks, your Nav component isn't going to render to the DOM since it's not being returned inside of the render() life cycle method. You're going to need to place it inside the existing DropdownMenuComponent render method or create a new component for the Nav and import it into the parent component in order for it to render properly.

Hope this helps!